# how to use variable data to use in template tag in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In **urls.py** file

```
from articles.views import home    

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^home/$',home.as_view(),name='home'),
 )
```

In **views.py** file

```
class home(TemplateView):
    template_name='article.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = Homeform()
        return render(request,self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self,request):
        file_path = '/u/vinay/checking.py'
        args={'file_path':file_path}
        return render(request,self.template_name, args)
```

In **article.html** file

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<body>

<a href="{% static '{{ file_path }}' %}" download ><button class="button button2">Download plan</button></a>

<p>{{ file_path }} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But i'm getting no file as output from GUI.

As i'm creating download link for that file in file_path location.So how do i render text from views to article.html

Answer (score 1):

You dont neeed `{{}}` signs inside template tag. Try this:

```
"{% static file_path %}"
```

Check django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) for details.

Comment: geting no file as output

Comment: @vinay Check rendered url in browser and do you have file on this address.

Comment: yes i have but even its not printing that value also as i tried <p>{{ file_path }}</p> but its not printing

Comment: @vinay your view function shoud take request as argument: `def vin(request)`. Can you add full code of views.py and urls.py files?

Comment: its not printing that variable data itself <p>{{ file_path }} </p>

Comment: @vinay Can you add full code of urls.py file and views.py file? If you add print('hello world') to vin function can you see it in console when you open url?

Comment: And the full template.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation for [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#static):

```
href="{% static file_path %}"
```

Ninja'ed..

Also, your view function is all messed up, I'm suprised it displays anything at all:

```
def vin(request):
    return render(request,'article.html', {'file_path':'xyz.py'})
```

---

Try this:

```
class home(TemplateView):
    template_name='article.html'

    def get_context_data(self,*args,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        context['file_path'] = '/u/vinay/checking.py'
        return context

# END OF VIEW --- no get or post method, let the generic view handle that.
```

Comment: I fear you do not quite understand how requests work. If you do not have anything that actually calls your view with a POST request, the post method will not fire. The generic TempateView does not contain a post method because its job is just displaying a template through GET requests. The easiest solution is to rename your 'post' method to a 'get' method. The cleanest solution is to remove your post method entirely and add the context variable 'file_path' in `get_context_data` method: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview)

Comment: i have get function srry i forgot to type

Comment: Your template does not do anything with the form you give it in the `get()` method. What is happening currently is: 1) the request comes in and `get()` is called 2) the template is being rendered, but it doesn't know what to do with the **context variable** `file_path`, because you didn't supply one in the `get()` method 3) instead it (the template) has a `form` context variable, that it doesn't use at all 4) meanwhile _you_ are expecting a post request from a page that simply cannot send any